# passive voice and potential voice

Tags: grammar, potential-form

I'm having troubles with distinguishing between passive voice and potential voice in the following sentences, help me please.

---

[image]

```
鍔姫：「だから、弟が幼稚園の頃、母に頼まれて、よく風呂にいれていてだな。その、だから見慣れているというか」
幼稚園の頃……？
それと比べられて平気って、おい。
鍔姫：「いや、別に沢山見ているわけではないが！ 何もかも平気というわけでもないが……」
鍔姫：「あ、いや、今は平気だった。別に気分など悪くしてないからな！ 断じてしていない！」
```

[image]

`”ファントム”の称号を与えるのは問題かとも思ったが……」
マグワイヤ
「もう異論はない。
彼女こそ”ファントム”」
マグワイヤ
「我がインフェルノのトップ＝スナイパーだ」
サイス
「いえ、どれもこれも、
ミズ＝マッキェネンの後ろ盾があればこそ、
成し遂げられた成果です」
マグワイヤ
「良い部下を待ったな、クロウディア」
クロウディア
「……」`

Some sort of translation: pic1 -

> When he was in kindergarten ? I was compared with him(this?), and she
>   is saying "everything is fine", hey. - passive.
>
> When he was in kindergarten ? She could compare me with him(this?),
>   and she is saying "everything is fine", hey. - potential.

pic2 -

> The results has been achieved only because of Miss McCunnen's help. -
>   passive.
>
> We(?) were able to do it only because of Miss McCunnen's help. -
>   potential.

As always thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. それと比べられて平気って、おい。
   Passive. The subjects for 比べられる and 平気(だ・でいる) are the speaker. (The subject of 比べる is 鍔姫. The speaker is saying that 鍔姫 is comparing his ✕✕✕ with her little brother's ✕✕✕... and says "... and you think I feel fine(=平気)? Hey." )
2. ～があればこそ、成し遂げられた～
   Potential. It's like "We managed/were able to do it only/precisely because we had Miss McCunnen's backup." 
   cf. 「これまでの蓄積があればこそ、今日までやってこられたのだ」[weblioばこそ](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B0%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D)

Comment: ×××をどうしたらいいかわかりません。。。

Comment: もしかして４文字？日本語だと３文字か４文字か５文字かな・・・